# Application won't exit after downloading a file with scala-ssh

Tags: scala, ssh, sshj

I'm using scala-ssh 0.7.0 to download a file from a remote server.

The download itself seems to be successful (I can find the downloaded file). Here is the last part of the log output:

> 16:14:43.824 [main] TRACE
>   net.schmizz.sshj.xfer.LoggingTransferListener -- **transferred 100% of
>   `log-file.txt`** 16:14:43.824 [main] INFO 
>   net.schmizz.sshj.common.StreamCopier -- 44.82421875 KiB transferred in
>   1.572 seconds (28.514134064885496 KiB/s) 16:14:43.825 [main] DEBUG net.schmizz.sshj.xfer.scp.SCPEngine -- **Remote agrees transfer done**
>   16:14:43.826 [main] DEBUG net.schmizz.sshj.xfer.scp.SCPEngine --
>   Signalling: Transfer done 16:14:43.826 [main] TRACE
>   net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Encoder -- Encoding packet #10: 5e 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 01 00 16:14:43.826 [main] DEBUG
>   net.schmizz.sshj.connection.channel.Window$Remote -- Consuming by 1
>   down to 2097148 16:14:44.220 [reader] TRACE
>   net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Decoder -- Received packet #14: 62 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 0b 65 78 69 74 2d 73 74 61 74 75 73 00 00 00 00 00
>   16:14:44.221 [reader] TRACE net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl
>   -- Received packet CHANNEL_REQUEST 16:14:44.221 [reader] DEBUG net.schmizz.sshj.connection.channel.direct.SessionChannel -- Got chan
>   request for `exit-status` 16:14:44.222 [reader] TRACE
>   net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Decoder -- Received packet #15: 60 00 00 00
>   00 16:14:44.222 [reader] TRACE
>   net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl -- Received packet
>   CHANNEL_EOF 16:14:44.222 [reader] DEBUG
>   net.schmizz.sshj.connection.channel.direct.SessionChannel -- Got EOF
>   16:14:44.223 [reader] TRACE net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Decoder --
>   Received packet #16: 61 00 00 00 00 16:14:44.223 [reader] TRACE
>   net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl -- Received packet
>   CHANNEL_CLOSE 16:14:44.223 [main] DEBUG
>   net.schmizz.sshj.connection.channel.direct.SessionChannel -- Sending
>   close 16:14:44.223 [reader] DEBUG
>   net.schmizz.sshj.connection.channel.direct.SessionChannel -- Got close
>   16:14:44.224 [main] TRACE net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Encoder --
>   Encoding packet #11: 61 00 00 00 00 16:14:44.225 [main] DEBUG
>   net.schmizz.concurrent.Promise -- Awaiting <>
>   16:14:44.225 [reader] DEBUG net.schmizz.sshj.connection.ConnectionImpl
>   -- Forgetting `session` channel (#0) 
>   16:14:44.225 [reader] DEBUG net.schmizz.concurrent.Promise -- Setting <> to `SOME`

My code is very simple:

```
import com.decodified.scalassh._

val sshClient = new SshClient(new HostConfig(login = PasswordLogin(userName, SimplePasswordProducer(password)), hostName))


sshClient.download(filePath, targetDirectory)
```

Now, although the download finishes successfully, and the application execution continues after the download command, the application itself doesn't exit.

Any ideas?

Comment: May it be related to https://github.com/sirthias/scala-ssh/pull/27 ?

Comment: Thank you @pedrofurla. It's seems to be linked -- when avoiding the implicit conversion to RichSshClient, the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implicit conversion to RichSshClient seems to be behind this. 
I avoided the implicit convertion to RichSshClient by creating a new class -- 'SshClientEnhanced' which extends SshClient with ScpTransferable. Invoking download method on an instance of SshClientEnhanced works fine.